# mySQL problem when retrieving result with quotation marks

Tags: php, mysql, quotation-marks

I'm having a problem with an SQL query on a php page.

I'm pretty new to php so stick with me.

I have successfully created a query to select everything, but I want to include a `WHERE` in the query. The trouble is that the result includes quotation marks because it is html code.

I'm sure this is simple but can anyone help... problem code below:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE text = '<span class="myclass">Here is my text</span>'");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Escape the quotation marks:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE text = '<span class=\"myclass\">Here is my text</span>'");
```

---

### Correct answer

You are almost certainly building this query dynamically (i.e., the string `<span class=\"myclass\">Here is my text</span>` is in a variable, let's call it `$searchTerm`).

**Do not, EVER,** execute SQL queries with embedded variables without escaping the variable contents first. This will not only prevent such problems, but it will also prevent SQL injection attacks against your application.

Assuming the `$searchTerm` variable as mentioned above, the correct way would be:

```
$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE text = \'%s\'',
                 mysql_real_escape_string($searchTerm));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

---

### Totally correct answer

Use PHP's PDO extension, which provides easy access to this functionality (read up on *variable binding*) and is also 100% secure (which `mysql_real_escape_string` is not -- but the topic is way too advanced to discuss here).

Comment: Short answer is incorrect and "totally correct" one is almost pointless as it contains no example and misleading. When properly used, mysql_real_escape_string is no less secure than any other method. PDO itself uses it occasionally

Comment: @Col: Thanks for the feedback, but I 'm way done arguing with you :)

Comment: @Col: Thanks for the downvote as well. But I guess we all knew that was coming.

Comment: @Col: By the way: *"When properly used, mysql_real_escape_string is no less secure than any other method"*. You may find this enlightening: http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html

Comment: this article is outdated. mysql has mysql_set_charset() for ages already

Comment: Thanks for this guys but for your information the arguing only really succeeds in confusing matters. I recommend you get a room!

Comment: @Tom anything particular still confusing you?

Comment: Nope... for the very basic purposes of my problem it was sufficient to just escape the quotations. Thanks

Comment: @Tom so, no escaping for SQL? Accept my condolences then

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the quotation marks by using `\"`. Better: escape your stuff using `mysql(i)_escape_string`. Best: Use PDO with prepared statements and let it escape everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

escape `"` sign in that way: `\"`

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in your code.

Your current problem is not SQL related but PHP syntax related. As you can see even from the syntax highlighting, double quotes breaks your string.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE text='<span class="myclass">Here is my text</span>'";
```

So, you have to either escape delimiting quotes,

```
$text = "<span class=\"myclass\">Here is my text</span>";
```

or use different quotes

```
$text = '<span class=\"myclass\">Here is my text</span>';
```

Next your problem is SQL related. You cannot put strings into query as is. you have to escape it for the query and only then put it into query.

```
$text = '<span class=\"myclass\">Here is my text</span>';
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE text='$text'";
```

Finally, you're running your query wrong. Do not write horizontally, write vertically. Put operators one under another, not in one grosse shange. And akways check query result to be informed of all possible errors:

```
$text = '<span class=\"myclass\">Here is my text</span>';
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE text='$text'";
$res  = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
```